# woocommerce-api with ionic3 and cordova

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm using ionic 3  to retrieve data from woocommerce and view them on the simulator, my problem is the code does get the array of data(JSON data) but won't show them on the simulator, here is the code I used

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at line number 27 in home.ts page

replace

```
this.products = JSON.parse(data.body).products
```

with

```
this.products = JSON.parse(data.body)
```

Comment: thats ok . thanks ... but there are many other problems like cors and some other errors in that project in github